# Extract only integer from a string in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to extract 4 digit integer within a string,I have tried with `^[[:digit:]]+` ,`[^0-9]+`
`[^\\d]+` but unable to find accurate 4 digit integer value.I have taken following example

```
Expression="sqrt((sin(3501)*cos(3505))^2+sin(3509)^2+cos(3508)^2)+9999.990"
sort(unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Expression, "[^0-9]+"))))))
[1]    2   9999  990 3501 3505 3508 3509
```

I want output as `3501 3505 3508 3509`.Any help,Any good link to prepare for regular expression in R,Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the below code,

```
> Expression="sqrt((sin(3501)*cos(3505))^2+sin(3509)^2+cos(3508)^2)+9999.990"
> m <- gregexpr("\\(\\K\\d{4}(?=\\))", Expression, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(Expression, m)
[[1]]
[1] "3501" "3505" "3509" "3508"
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` Matches a literal `(` symbol.
- `\K` Discards the previously matched characters from printing. So in our case, it discards the previously matched `(` symbol.
- `\d{4}` Matches exactly four digits.
- `(?=\))` Positive lookahead asserts that the character following the four digits must be a closing parenthesis.

**OR**

```
> Expression="sqrt((sin(3501)*cos(3505))^2+sin(3509)^2+cos(3508)^2)+9999.990"
> m <- gregexpr("(?<![.\\d])\\d{4}(?![.\\d])", Expression, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(Expression, m)
[[1]]
[1] "3501" "3505" "3509" "3508"
```

Comment: Wow ,Already given +1 but just for curiosity, what does "K" do over here?

Comment: you could use lookbehind instead of `\K`, like `(?<=\\()`

Comment: If the 4 digit number is not in brackets `()` then above won't work? `Expression="sqrt((sin(3501)*cos(3505))^2+sin(3509)^2+cos(3508)^2)+9999.990*1234"`